# Error Connecting MySQL Database with Node.js in Angular Universal. TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, angular-universal

I would like to connect to MySQL database through Node.js in my Angular Universal project.

Connection code is simple:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'localhost',
          user     : 'root',
          password : 'root',
          database : 'dbname',
          port: '8889'
        });

connection.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error connecting to DB: " + err);
            throw err;
          }
        });
```

First I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
        at Protocol._enqueue (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Angular2/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:152:5)
...
```

Then after several seconds there is the following error:

```
Error connecting to DB: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
```

Advice me please what should be done in this case to fix the issue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If I change the version for zone.js in package.json to 0.7.4, everything works without problems.

Comment: The issue was solved when I install the latest version of Zone.js: npm install zone.js@latest.